# add .cer file to okhttp

Tags: android, https, okhttp

I am using okhttp in my project and recently switched to https
the admin sent a .cer 
and i tried to add it but all examples uses a hash from the certificate
like this

```
val certificatePinner = CertificatePinner.Builder()
   .add(
           "www.example.com",
           "sha256/ZC3lTYTDBJQVf1P2V7+fibTqbIsWNR/X7CWNVW+CEEA="
   ).build()

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
   .build()
```

is there a way to add the .cer
or how to get the sha from it?

Comment: you can use `.cert`  file which can be provided by backend and add it to the resource and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You‘ll want to load the certificate into your trust store, as in OkHttp’s [CustomTrust.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) example:

```
X509TrustManager trustManager;
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
try {
  trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(trustedCertificatesInputStream());
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
  sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
    .build();
```